# How to Remove Duplicate Content Errors without 301s or Canonicalization?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content

I use Moz to crawl my site for meta errors, and I've gotten a lot of 'duplicate content' errors. In some cases, it says that page x has duplicate content to over 100 pages.

I believe that pages are marked as dupes if 90% of the code or content match, which might be true for these pages since the header and footer contain a majority of the code for these pages. Otherwise, these pages are in fact fairly unique to one another.

Since they are unique, I can't use 301s or canonicalization to fix it. Is there another way? Should I ignore the dupe content errors?

Thanks

Comment: If they are not actually duplicate you don't have to do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the pages are unique, you're good. You don't have to take action on everything Moz flags. I use Moz heavily, and see flags here and there that might seem like issues to them, but in the context of the websites I'm working on are actually not issues for search engines or for users. You can set Moz to ignore those issues in the future, and make sure that the meta tags you use on these pages (title, description) are distinct.